# Access results from php/mysql query

Tags: php, mysql

I have a simple command in php to test whether or not data exists in my mySQL database:

```
$query      = "SELECT distinct name from table where number = '$part'";
$result     = mysqli_query($con, $crossSupplierQuery);
```

I do a bunch of code after this, but I want to enclose the entire thing inside of an if statement so that if this *initial* query doesn't provide any results, I can skip over the rest of the code.  I tried a simple `if ($result) {` , but that doesn't work as `$result` is always populated with SOMETHING.  I tried digging deeper into the object it creates and I get this object:

```
object(mysqli_result)#2 (5) {
  ["current_field"]=>
  int(0)
  ["field_count"]=>
  int(1)
  ["lengths"]=>
  NULL
  ["num_rows"]=>
  int(0)
  ["type"]=>
  int(0)
}
```

The value that determines whether or not the initial query found results is (I believe) held in `["num_rows"]=>`, but I can't access that using `$result['num_rows']` since this is an object, not an array.

What syntax would I use to accomplish what I'm trying to do with my `if` statement?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can access elements of an object using the following syntax:

```
echo $crossSupplierResult->{'num_rows'};
```

put curly braces around the element, (in this case, `num_rows`)

Comment: Perfect!  I utilized this in the following statement and it works to filter the `if` statement exactly as I wanted it to:  `if ($result->{'num_rows'} == 1)`